# Stop notifications from chrome spam

Tags: applications

My new Android device is full of spams. I get chrome notifications continuously from a website I did not even visit once. looks like a gossip site. Are there any methods to stop these annoying notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open Chrome, then Settings,select Site Settings
2. Click on Notifications. Check if that website is listed among the Allowed sites.
3. If yes, Click on it. Remove or block the permissions given to it by clicking on the permissions

Comment: Thank you. the answer is really very helpful.it worked.

Comment: @KevinBarnes Please see the [Tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) on how to the site works. If the answer helped you, then you can mark it as accepted.